# PHP get multiple files

Tags: php, forms

I have an input of type **file** with property **multiple**. With this property I can select multiple files. How can I adress these files after submit with PHP?

Using this script and selcting multiple files, the output only contains 1 file:

```
  <?php
    print_r($_FILES);
  ?>

  <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name='file' multiple >
     <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

Here is the output:

```
Array ( 
 [file] => Array ( 
        [name] => firefox.exe 
        [type] => application/octet-stream 
        [tmp_name] => /is/htdocs/user_tmp/wp10991132_7P7886URU4/phpO5UJ59 
        [error] => 0 
        [size] => 392136 
        ) 
 )
```

Where are the other files?

Comment: please post what you see for `print_r($_FILES);` after you try your script

Comment: @cmorrissey I added the output now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use array as name of HTML input

```
<input type="file" name='file[]' multiple >
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HTML:  
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple >
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

To get them in PHP as described here:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

```
PHP:  

$first_file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'][0];
$second_file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'][1];

$first_file_tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][0];
$second_file_tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][1];

$first_file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'][0];
$second_file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'][1];
//and so on...
```

You can see here what browser versions support this possibility:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp
(for instance multiple attribute is not supported under IE 10)